# Compare radio button values with values in Database

Tags: php, html, forms, radio-button

I have a column in my database called "answer" which consist of three options, option_a, option_b and option_c. My form/quiz is set up to where each question has three answers option_a, option_b and option_c. When the form is submitted to results.php I need to compare the submitted answers with the actual answers from database. It's like a quiz application.

How do I call the array of radio button values to display and be compared on results.php?

code from quiz.php

```
  //looping for numbers
  $counter=0;

 $mydata = mysql_query($mysql,$con);
 //post quiz name (here)
 echo $name."</br>";
 while($records = mysql_fetch_array($mydata)){

echo "<div>";
     echo $records['question_description']."<br>";

    //image displayed here  

    echo "<label><input type='radio' name='option".$counter."' value=".$records['option_a'].">".$records['option_a']."</label><br>";

     echo "<label><input type='radio' name='option".$counter."' value=".$records['option_b'].">".$records['option_b']."</label><br>";

     echo "<label><input type='radio' name='option".$counter."' value=".$records['option_c'].">".$records['option_c']."</label><br>";
     $counter++;

     echo "</ br> <hr>";
echo "</div>";
 }

 echo "<input type=submit value=Submit Quiz>";
```

How do I get this information over to my next page after submitting the form? I hope you can understand my problem.

Comment: Are you asking how to detect for what was submitted by the form?

Comment: What does javascript have to do with this? are you trying to use ajax?

Comment: Yes, I need to detect, display and compare everything that was submitted from the form into another page. Unless it is earlier to do all of the above on the same page.

Comment: Well, do you have a form element? Wrap these input in a form element, set an action attribute on your form and you should be able to access the values through `$_POST` or `$_GET` in php.

Comment: @ohgodwhy I said javascript because all the web sites that I've looked at have use javascript.

Comment: @plalx I do have these wrapped in a form as a post method. I just can't figure out how to run a loop to display what was submitted.

Comment: In this case, the usage you desire can be completed without any javascript what so ever.

Answer (score 0):

Surround all the `input` tags with a `form` tag.

```
<form action="urlofnextpage" method="POST"> <!-- Method can also be GET -->

<input...>
<input...>
<input...>
<input type="submit">

</form>
```

On the next page:

```
<?php
$option1 = $_POST['name attribute of the input element'];
$option2 = $_POST['name attribute of the input element'];
$option3 = $_POST['name attribute of the input element'];
?>
```

If it isn't sensitive information, you can use `GET`, but that will clutter the URL.

> I do have these wrapped in a form as a post method. I just can't figure out how to run a loop to display what was submitted. –  Jordan

In that case you can use an array:

```
$options = array();
for($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++)
{
    options[$i] = $_POST["option" . $i];
}
```

Here are some links:

http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_looping_for.asp

http://www.tizag.com/phpT/postget.php

http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_forms.asp

Comment: I fixed a mistake in the for loop, in case you've already tried to use it. I replaced `"option" + $i` with `"option" . $i`. I forgot that concatenation in PHP is with a ".".